# How to fit image to a particular div (bootstrap)

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3, styling

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<!-- jQuery library -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- Latest compiled JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

 <div class="card" style="height: 20em;width: 17em;">
        <div style="height:17em;width:17em;background-color: #5f5f5f">
            <img class="card-img-top" src="http://haulihuvila.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/09/hauli-huvila-campgrounds-lg.jpg">
        </div>
        <div class="card-body">
            <h3 class="card-title">help me</h3>
            <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">More Info</a>
        </div>
    </div>
```

How do I resize image to the size of div.
I have already tried giving img a class having max-width as 100% and max-height as 100%.

Comment: Hi and welcome to StackOverflow. Please refer to https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask on how to ask a proper question and improve yours according the guidelines. As a first step, please add the code you already tried and describe how it doesnt work for you.

Answer (score 0):

by giving max-height and max-width, the image is resizing add your css.. to see if there is something blocking those properties

```css
.card-img-top{
  max-width:100%;
  max-height:100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="card" style="height: 20em;width: 17em;">
    <div style="height:17em;width:17em;background-color: #5f5f5f">
        <img class="card-img-top" src="http://haulihuvila.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/09/hauli-huvila-campgrounds-lg.jpg">
    </div>
    <div class="card-body">
        <h3 class="card-title">help me</h3>
        <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">More Info</a>
    </div>
</div
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to fit image in a div use `background-image` instead of `<img>`

***Stack Snippet***

```css
.bg {
  background-image: url(http://haulihuvila.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/09/hauli-huvila-campgrounds-lg.jpg);
  height: 17em;
  width: 17em;
  background-color: #5f5f5f;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center center;
}
```

```html
<div class="card" style="height: 20em;width: 17em;">
  <div class="bg"></div>
  <div class="card-body">
    <h3 class="card-title">help me</h3>
    <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">More Info</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

> Use [Css3 background](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_background.asp) that gives you more control over images in
>   div.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<style>
.class1{
 background-size: 100% 100%;
    background-image: url(http://haulihuvila.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/09/hauli-huvila-campgrounds-lg.jpg);
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="card" style="height: 20em;width: 17em;">
    <div class="class1" style="height:17em;width:17em;background-color: #5f5f5f">
        
    </div>
    <div class="card-body">
        <h3 class="card-title">help me</h3>
        <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">More Info</a>
    </div>
</div
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to keep the aspect of the image just set the background in a div.

HTML

```
<div class="card" style="height: 20em;width: 17em;">
    <div style="height:17em;width:17em;background-color: #5f5f5f">
        <div class="card-img-top"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="card-body">
        <h3 class="card-title">help me</h3>
        <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">More Info</a>
    </div>
</div
```

CSS

```
.card-img-top {
  background: url('http://haulihuvila.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/09/hauli-huvila-campgrounds-lg.jpg') no-repeat center center;
  background-size: cover;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```